# Probability measure satisfying curvature-dimension

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Assume that the non-compact $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ satisfies a curvature-dimension $\mathrm{CD}(K,N)$, $K \le 0$, with respect to a measure $\mu = e^{-V} d\mathrm{Vol}$; i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Ric} + \mathrm{Hess} V - \frac{\nabla V \otimes \nabla V}{N - n} \ge Kg.
\end{equation*}
I wonder if it possible to have $\mu$ as a probability measure? The only example of $\mathrm{CD}(K,N)$ in this non-compact case I know is from the [monograph of Villani - example 14.10](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf):
\begin{equation*} \mu(dx) = \cosh^{N-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{|K|}{N-1}}x\right)dx\end{equation*}
which is clearly not normalizable.